# format specifies type 'unsigned long long' but the argument has type 'unsigned int'

Tags: c++

I am working on some C++ code and I'm getting a warning while compiling.  I know it doesn't really affect the end result, but I like code to be as clean as possible, the warning is:

```
src/main.cpp:1908:136: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long long' but the argument has type 'unsigned int' [-Wformat]
  ...: Rejected by stake modifier checkpoint height=%d, modifier=0x%016"PRIx64, pindexNew->nHeight, pindexNew->nStakeModifierChecksum);
                                                                   ~~~~~                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the code in question is:

```
    uint64_t nStakeModifier = 0;
    bool fGeneratedStakeModifier = false;
    if (!ComputeNextStakeModifier(pindexNew->pprev, nStakeModifier, fGeneratedStakeModifier))
        return error("AddToBlockIndex() : ComputeNextStakeModifier() failed");
    pindexNew->SetStakeModifier(nStakeModifier, fGeneratedStakeModifier);
    pindexNew->nStakeModifierChecksum = GetStakeModifierChecksum(pindexNew);
    if (!CheckStakeModifierCheckpoints(pindexNew->nHeight, pindexNew->nStakeModifierChecksum))
        return error("AddToBlockIndex() : Rejected by stake modifier checkpoint height=%d,  modifier=0x%016"PRIx64, pindexNew->nHeight, pindexNew->nStakeModifierChecksum);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have some printf()-like code where the placeholder in the format string doesn't match with the according value. You have to change either of them so that they match.

That said, please in future do some research yourself and provide a minimal example. How is anyone supposed to analyze the issue if you don't provide info about `pindexNew->nStakeModifierChecksum` or `error()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this stuff and just playing with a fork of existing code.

Comment: Its in main.h as     unsigned int nStakeModifierChecksum; // checksum of index; in-memeory only

Comment: No, sorry, still not clear. Please create a single .cpp file that contains a single main() function that demonstrates the issue. This should actually be the first step for you to understanding the problem, even before asking here.